# 404 Error when trying to install sbt through brew

Tags: scala, sbt, homebrew

I'm trying to `brew install sbt` and getting this:

```
==> Downloading http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.5/sbt-launch.jar

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found Error:
Failed to download resource "sbt" Download failed:
http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.5/sbt-launch.jar
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Did you `brew update` first? When I do `brew install`, it installs 0.13.12. 0.13.5 is a very old version; the launch jars moved to a different server a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer not to install it globally. Use:

```
$ cat get_sbt.sh
#!/bin/bash

curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt > sbt \
  && chmod 0755 sbt
```

Then run with:

`./sbt`

It will download the latest for you.

Comment: I did something like that eventually. Thanks!